# Consolidation of dynamically changing data in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I work with data including unique names of customers and values of their purchases. I want to conduct its consolidation, meaning the result would be customers and their total sums of purchase like in the picture below:

[image]

The data is changing after every VBA code operation (new customers come in, old disappear, new transactions are recorded etc.) which somehow leads to this line of code generating errors:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range(D2).Consolidate Sources:=Array(Sheet1!R2C1:R3C51), Function:=xlSum
```

Is there a different approach to this situation so that there's no problem with getting the right results?

Comment: What is the error generated by that line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use excel formulas instead of vba.

Fomula for D2:

`=IFERROR(INDEX($A$3:$A$7, MATCH(0,COUNTIF($D$1:D1, $A$3:$A$7), 0)),"")`

and hit **CTR+SHIFT+ENTER**

Then use sumif in E2:

`=SUMIF($A$2:$A$7, D2, $B$2:$B$7)`

Drop the cell down.

Answer (score 0):

### Sum Up Unique

- Consider a table (not necessarily `Excel` table) with two columns: the first containing the keys and the second containing their values.
- These solutions will write the **unique** keys (not sorted) and the **sum** of their values to another table.
- Adjust the values in the constants section.

**Remarks**

- Note the 4th argument `LeftColumn` of [`Consolidate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.consolidate) set to `True`:

  - *True to consolidate data based on row titles in the left column of the consolidation ranges. False to consolidate data by position. The default value is False.* (`Microsoft Docs`)
- Surprisingly, there is no need for the `Array` function most probably because there is only one range to consolidate.
- Although the `Consolidate` solution contains less code and maybe more 'user friendly' (easier to understand), it seems that the `Dictionary` version is more efficient (not tested properly).

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub sumUpDictionary()
    
    ' Constants
    Const srcName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const srcFirst As String = "A2"
    Const dstName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const dstFirst As String = "D2"
    Const cCount As Long = 2
    
    ' Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' Source Range to Data Array.
    Dim cel As Range
    Dim Data As Variant
    With wb.Worksheets(srcName).Range(srcFirst)
        Set cel = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If cel Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        Data = .Resize(cel.Row - .Row + 1, cCount)
    End With
    
    ' Data Array to Unique Sum Dictionary to Data Array.
    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        .CompareMode = vbTextCompare
        Dim Key As Variant
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 1 To UBound(Data)
            Key = Data(i, 1)
            If Not IsError(Key) Then
                If Len(Key) > 0 Then
                    .Item(Key) = .Item(Key) + Data(i, 2)
                End If
            End If
        Next i
        If .Count = 0 Then Exit Sub
        ReDim Data(1 To .Count, 1 To cCount)
        i = 0
        For Each Key In .Keys
            i = i + 1
            Data(i, 1) = Key
            Data(i, 2) = .Item(Key)
        Next Key
    End With
    
    ' Data Array to Destination Range.
    With wb.Worksheets(dstName).Range(dstFirst).Resize(, cCount)
        .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1).ClearContents
        .Resize(i).Value = Data
    End With

End Sub

Sub sumUpConsolidate()
    
    ' Constants
    Const srcName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const srcFirst As String = "A2"
    Const dstName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const dstFirst As String = "D2"
    Const cCount As Long = 2
    
    ' Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' Source
    Dim cel As Range
    Dim Data As Variant
    Dim consString  As String
    With wb.Worksheets(srcName).Range(srcFirst)
        Set cel = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If cel Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        consString = "'" & .Worksheet.Name & "'" _
            & "!" & "R" & .Row & "C" & .Column _
            & ":" & "R" & cel.Row & "C" & .Column + cCount - 1
        ' or:
        'consString = "'" & .Worksheet.Name & "'" _
            & "!" & .Address(, , xlR1C1) _
            & ":" & cel.Resize(, cCount).Address(, , xlR1C1)
    End With
    
    ' Destination
    With wb.Worksheets(dstName).Range(dstFirst)
        .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1, cCount).ClearContents
        .Consolidate consString, xlSum, , True
    End With

End Sub
```